# MS Access Textbox Default Value Max Size Limit

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, stored-procedures

I have the following setup:

I have a form with unbound textbox controls. I have a procedure that fires after every AfterUpdate event.

The procedure sends the input value to a table and returns the value input in the table as the textbox's DefaultValue. The table defines unique rows by the form and control name, 2 primary keys.

After data is input, there is a button that sends data from the form in a structured way to another table and a report reads off the table. The data is input into the table in a structured way with an SQL query.

The problem is when a user inputs texts over 2048 characters in two of the fields, the code breaks due to the limit. Two of the fields on the form, on each page will likely have over 2k characters due to the nature of the forms.

My question is, can I circumvent, increase or bypass the character limit?

My code is posted below for reference if needed (Procedure called OptimizeS is loaded in every textbox on the form):

Procedure that writes the input value to the table:

```
Private Sub OptimizeS()
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strForm As String
Dim strControl As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strCriteria As String

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

strCriteria = "FormName = """ & Me.Name & """ " & _
"And ControlName = """ & Me.ActiveControl.Name & """"
' is there an existing default for this control?
If Not IsNull(DLookup("FormName", "Defaults", strCriteria)) Then
' if so then update row in table
strSQL = "UPDATE Defaults " & _
"SET DefaultVal = """ & Me.ActiveControl & """ " & _
"WHERE " & strCriteria
Else
' insert new row
strSQL = "INSERT INTO Defaults(" & _
"FormName,ControlName,DefaultVal) " & _
"VALUES(""" & Me.Name & """,""" & _
Me.ActiveControl.Name & """,""" & _
Me.ActiveControl & """)"
End If

cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.Execute
End Sub
```

Support Procedures on the form itself:

1)

```
Private Sub Form_MouseMove(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strOpened As String
Dim strForm As String
Dim strSQL As String

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

strOpened = "Opened = """ & Me.Name & """ "

If Not IsNull(DLookup("Opened", "AllOpened", strOpened)) Then
strSQL = "UPDATE AllOpened " & _
"SET Opened = """ & Me.Name & """ " & _
"WHERE " & strOpened
Else
strSQL = "INSERT INTO AllOpened(Opened) " & _
"VALUES(""" & Me.Name & """)"
End If

cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.Execute
End Sub
```

2)

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strCriteria As String
Dim strOpened As String
Dim varDefault As Variant
Dim varOpened As Variant
Dim strForm As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim ctrl As Control

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

strOpened = "Opened = """ & Me.Name & """ "

varOpened = DLookup("Opened", "AllOpened", strOpened)
If IsNull(varOpened) Then
strSQL = "INSERT INTO AllOpened(Opened) " & _
"VALUES(""" & Me.Name & """)"
cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.Execute
Else
GoTo ErrMsg
End If

For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
strCriteria = "FormName = """ & Me.Name & """ " & _
"And ControlName = """ & ctrl.Name & """"

varDefault = DLookup("DefaultVal", "Defaults", strCriteria)
If Not IsNull(varDefault) Then
ctrl.DefaultValue = """" & varDefault & """"
End If
Next ctrl
Exit Sub
ErrMsg:
MsgBox ("The form is already open by another user. Please double-check before editing."), , "Important!!!"
End Sub
```

3)

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strForm As String
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

strSQL = "DELETE FROM AllOpened " & _
        "WHERE Opened = """ & Me.Name & """"

cmd.CommandText = strSQL
cmd.Execute

End Sub
```

Comment: You are really making life difficult for yourself. Why don't you just bind the form to the table? That's what _Access_ is designed for. If you don't like that, go with tools like _Visual Studio_ with _WinForms_ and _VB.NET_ or _C#_.

Comment: It can't really be done like, I would have done it if I could. The form needs to be able to hold data and serve as an insert/edit/delete-platform. WinForms isn't really an option. Is there a way I can transit the long text through an element of some kind? Or create a different kind of object that doesn't have the char limit?

Comment: Well, if you've found that a 2K string is the max that DefaultValue can hold, that's it. There's no place where a setting can change this. So you will have to create some kind of workaround with a lookup table or the like.

Comment: The Dlookup was the problem, it can't search pass 2000 characters in a Memo field. I used Left to limit the search to the first 2000 characters and to fix it. I'm facing another issue now though. At the second procedure, at ctrl.DefaultValue = """" & varDefault & """" -> it says that the expression is longer than 2,048 characters. Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't that your original issue? Which I see no solution to based on your experience.

Comment: The original issue used to trigger on the Dlookup. What did you mean a lookup table?

Comment: Oh, missed that. A lookup table could hold a _key_ and a _memo_ field with more than 2K text. Not sure how to apply it though.

Comment: The issue seems to be that VBA recognizes `ctrl.DefaultValue = """" & varDefault & """"` as an expression altogether and gives the error because it understands that the expression it recognizes is over 2048 characters. The `varDefault` output is actually text taken from the table. I'm not sure why this is happening though...maybe a wrong definition or quotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a hint in your last comment. Then try this verbose code using string variable that for sure doesn't have a 2K limit:

```
Dim DefaultString As String

DefaultString = Nz(varDefault)
ctrl.DefaultValue = DefaultString
```

Comment: Very Nice! I didn't use Nz, but rather something else I used the below code: `varDefault = DLookup("DefaultVal", "Defaults", strCriteria)
LMeasure = Left(varDefault, 2000)
MyLen = Len(varDefault)

If MyLen > 2000 Then
ctrl.DefaultValue = """" & LMeasure & """"
ctrl.Value = varDefault
Else
    If Not IsNull(varDefault) Then
    ctrl.DefaultValue = """" & varDefault & """"
    End If
End If` Basically it searches by the defaultvalue, but displays the full text in the value property from the table on load. .Value in forms is temporary, but not if it's loaded every time :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the feedback.